# Looking for code snippets, library, or toolkit to modify a USB Flash Drive's serial number

Tags: usb-drive

I've been writing some tools to interact with a USB Flash Drive (removable drive) for our portable application. We are going to be tying some relevant information directly to the flash drive via the serial number (device serial number, not the volume serial number which is formatting based)

I am able to read the device serial number. What is required to write/modify that device serial number?

I am open to seeing this in any language really (Perl, Ruby, Python, C/C++, .NET anything, etc)  but C# is the current code base so what would be first preference.

If a code snippet or script can't be found, some canned application or tool (binary, etc) or similar would be helpful as well.

Comment: Is there no one with any way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think the serial number you are refering to is hardware coded to the flash drive (ie. in its ROM). So there is no way you can (easily) change that serial number. Even if the serial was printed in reprogrammable ROM (I forgot the name EPROM or EEPROM), but then you still need a EPROM writer to do that, not only bunch of codes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I have to think this must be possible since the OEM for the drives did produce a piece of software written by Alcor that is supposed to do just this, however we just couldn't get it working correctly and wanted to write our own tool - especially since all the instructions were in Chinese :-)

Comment: I managed to find a link that points to several other Alcor products / versions and one thought is to go back and try all of them until one works. http://sosfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/where-to-download-alcor-tools-to-fix-fake-usb-flash-drives/ ... still, I'd rather either find someone who knows one that works or write the tool ourselves.

Comment: I visited the site, so this is about those "fake" ush flashdrives? Note that I have no direct experience with them, but the fact that they are "fakes" indicates they are not meeting the standard quality. I suspect they actually are meant to be destroyed by the manufactures but "stolen", internal chips got modified, and sold for non-suspecting customers. OR they are simply haven't been "finalized" yet (as in their ROM be closed from further writing).

Comment: Anyway, Windows api DeviceIoControl api is the one you should use to "talk" to the flash drives. However you still need very specific information for effective communication with the device.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is one data structure named CIS(**Card Information Structure**) "embedded" in USB flash drive and stored in flash memory. It is not stored in ROM but in flash, thus it can be modified. But unfortunately the only way to modify it is `via specific vendor commands` and general users don't know it, unless you can get help from the firmware programmer in charge of this flash controller IC...

Answer (score 0):

In a legitimate way it cannot be done, however if you have the correct MP tool for the built-in USB controller it is possible to modify the serial number and the whole digital structure of the drive.